# What does ruby syntax mean?

Tags: ruby, printf

```
task('google:rankings' => :environment) do
  def find_item uri, query
    search = Google::Search::Web.new do |search|
      search.query = query
      search.size = :large
      search.each_response { print '.'; $stdout.flush }
    end
    search.find { |item| item.uri.downcase.include?(uri.downcase) }
  end

  def rank_for query, domain
    print "%35s " % query
    if item = find_item(domain, query)
      puts " #%d" % (item.index + 1)
    else
      puts " Not found"
    end
  end

  Campaign.all.each do |campaign|
    campaign.keywords.each do |keyword|
      rank_for keyword.set, Domain.find(campaign.domain_id).name if (keyword.set)
    end
  end
end
```

This tidbit is inside of a rake task. When the rake task run the console window updates in real-time like so:

> keyword .
>
> keyword ...
>
> keyword ..... not found

I'm not exactly clear about what's going on with `#%d`? How is it making the printing of the dot happen multiple times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dots are not being printed by line 4 (or any line) of `rank_for`. They're being printed by the block passed to `search.each_response` several lines earlier.

In `#%d`, the `#` is just a `#` and the `%d` is a C-ish format code meaning "interpolate an integer value here".

Comment: dangit just barely saw it myself. what is %35s in that case?

Comment: @Jake %s means to take a string and the 35 right-aligns it to 35 characters.